# Code signing certificate across Multiple OS Platforms - Relating to Adobe Air packages

Tags: windows, ios, flex4, blackberry-playbook, digital-certificate

I am developing an application in Flex using Adobe Flash Builder 4.5 and I want to distribute this as an AIR package so that it will work on multiple Operating Systems. I am wanting to target the usual suspects :- 
Windows [what I currently develop on] 
Apple [As I understand I need an actual Mac in order to package it] ?
Blackberry Playbook. [Again I believe I need the actual Playbook etc] ?

I also want to eventually deploy the application to the Mobile platform. So that also means targetting Android. Now as far as I am aware, and all research indicates this, I can develop my single application in Flash Builder 4.5 and then deploy to all these platforms. Am I correct in this?
Now to my real question. Obviously I am aware that the application needs to be digitally signed, so can I purchase ONE digital certificate to sign for ALL Operating Systems? The reason I am confused on this is because I know there is something I need to purchase from Apple ($99 per year reacurring) but is that just to distribute via iTunes network or is that a certificate as well ? Presuming it is, can I use said certificate for all the above platforms ?
As you can tell I am probably getting everything all crossed up and confusing myself LOL, so some help would be greatly appreciated.
Regards Anthoni

EDIT:- Found this link [url]http://codesigning.ksoftware.net/[/url]
Apparently it is a Comodo code signing certificate and it lists the platforms as both Adobe AIR AND Apple. Has anyone experiance with this code certificate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comodo certificates do work on all of the platforms you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Mitchell. Can you confirm that they work also for the iPhone / iOS platform as well? If so, do I still need to purchase the $99 from Apple (although I believe that is so I can publish in iTunes mainly).

Comment: Yes, they do. I'm talking to a number of people these days that are using these certificates for iOS. As far as I know you don't need anything from Apple in addition to the single Comodo cert (which you can use on multiple platforms).

Comment: Thanks for this. Definately much appreciated.